# CSS: can't eliminate space on inline list

Tags: html, css, margin, spacing

I've built a CSS navbar on the bottom. For some reason, there is this little buffer on the left side, and nothing seems to eliminate it. This prevents my links from centering correctly.

I've tried `padding-left: -10px`, but it doesn't move left, even when `padding-left: 10px` DOES move it to the right.

```
body {
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}
    html, body, #map {
    height: 100%;
        }

footer {
    position: fixed;
    bottom: 0; 
    left: 0;
    height: 35px;
    width: 100%;
    font-size: 12px;
    background-color: black;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    padding-left: 0;
    list-style-type: none;
    text-decoration: none;
    text-align:center;
    letter-spacing:2px;
    float: none;
}

ul li {
    display: inline;
    background:url('images/sep.svg') no-repeat top left;
     padding-left: 10px
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
    list-style-type: none;
    color: #DFC184;
    a:visited: blue;
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/EHXxS/
http://jsfiddle.net/EHXxS/embedded/result/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
#nav {
    padding:0;
}
```

seems to fix it. **[jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/EHXxS/2/)**

Comment: Excellent! Thanks. It seems like the ul had an inherent border perhaps?

Comment: Yes, by default a `<ul>` has padding.